# Github multiple status checks for pull request

Tags: github, teamcity, github-api

I have a teamcity project running a build against github repo. On completion of the build, it uses a build feature of teamcity named "Report Change Status to Github" which reports the build status using - https://api.github.com

Now I would like to have another teamcity project run a build against the same github repo and report the build status to github.

How do I make github display the 2 status checks differently? Despite the 2 builds reporting status to github, github just displays "1 pending check" or "1 status check completed successfully"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit: I didn't realize you already have the plug in installed, but I am going to leave the steps for other users. I think you need separate build configurations and to make sure you customize the `context` setting.

I was playing with this today and you can't use JetBrains "Commit Status Reporter" to do this. You can use this plugin though: https://github.com/jonnyzzz/TeamCity.GitHub

It wasn't straightforward to install--

1. Go here (choose `Log in as guest`): https://teamcity.jetbrains.com/viewType.html?buildTypeId=bt398 and
2. Click the "View" link in the "Artifacts" column in the latest successful build.
3. Then you click `teamcity.github.zip` and it will download a zip file
4. Then you upload that zip to TeamCity in the plugins section
5. Once you do that, go to Build Features and click "Add Build Feature" and select "Report change status to GitHub".
6. Then fill the form out with something like this (Note: You will need this for each build configuration you want reported. I am also running each build on separate agents which might be necessary):

[image: TeamCity with Github Statuses]

Comment: Does the TC URL need to be accessible publicly for status checks to work? @ratherblue

Comment: No, it can be internal. TeamCity will poll GitHub for the statuses in that situation. @Ruskin

Comment: Thanks, can you help with this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38046167/tc-status-checks-are-not-showing-as-status-checks) or (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050749/how-can-i-create-a-status-on-github-for-my-repo) please? @ratherblue

Comment: @Ruskin looks like you got it figured out in the other question. Let me know if you run into any other issues

Comment: @ratherblue Does this plugin post `Test case` failures instead of specifying the build has failed? In my case build failed with 4 test cases(we can view this in build overview), is this plugin get the result and post on github? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user6136315 not that i'm aware of. I believe you have to link to the failed test. Although github is always improving their services so it might be possible since this answer is 1.5 years old

Comment: Thanks @ratherblue. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @ratherblue not working either with TeamCity 2017.1 or 2017.1.1. I uploaded that zip file and restarted TeamCity, the plugin not shoed up in the plugin list and build feature has not been updated.

Answer (score 3):

Statuses are created with something called a context:

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/#create-a-status

For each commit, the latest status for each context is shown. And for the pull request overall (next to the merge button) the latest per-context statuses of the latest commit in the pull request are shown.

This means that if you want multiple status checks to show up -- those statuses need to be created with different contexts. And that's something defined by the application which is creating statuses, not GitHub. GitHub only displays the statuses.